# In VS Code, how can I automatically focus on the line when a breakpoint hits, even at the same file

Tags: visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio, there is this feature that when a breakpoint is hit, no matter which tab the user is currently looking at, it always jumps to the breakpoint file, and center the breakpoint line. In fact, if the file is not open at the moment, Visual Studio will open that file in a new tab then focus the line.

Visual Studio Code currently has most of the feature replicated. Unfortunately, it's strangely missing a key part: if user is currently at the same file the breakpoint hits, it doesn't move the view to the breakpoint line. This behavior is annoying that sometimes I launch a debug session, while waiting for the program to compile, scroll to other part of the file, then seemingly nothing happens. I honestly thought the compilation might failed, but there is no error in problems, and get confused. Turns out it hits a breakpoint above (out of the view).

Is there setting to change the behavior? Otherwise, is there any hack to achieve this? Should I ask for a feature request?

Comment: Do you hace both of these settings enabled: `Debug: Focus Window on Break` and `Debug: Focus Editor on Break`?  (both default to enabled)

Comment: Yes. Both enabled. And they are working indeed, as I mentioned. However, it seems we might need another setting like `Debug: Focus Line on Break`. Wonder why they haven't added this, given Visual Studio had this for years.

Comment: At least in ts/js if I am focused in the same file (not on a breakpoint) it does move to the breakpoint hit line.  What language are you seeing this in?  Maybe the debug adapter you are using doesn't support this feature?

Comment: @Mark, I tried C++, PowerShell, Python, Node.js (all, with Microsoft's extension) and Rust (with rust-analyzer), none of them auto-focus. Could you package a minimum reproducible workspace that I can try? Also, do you happen to know which language feature is responsible for this?

Comment: @starball, Here you are: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/191013. Thank you!

Comment: do you have smooth scrolling enabled? does the problem go away if you disable it?

Comment: Yes. We found in https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/191013 that smooth scroll is causing the symptom. Still waiting for a fix...

Answer (score -1):

The issue is being tracked in [Automatically focus on the line when a breakpoint hits, even at the same file #191013](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/191013). Apparently it's already supposed to work this way. Determining the cause of it *not* working that way is still ongoing, but so far it's been found that the issue only happens when smooth scrolling is enabled and possibly only when debugging C++.

It somehow seemed to get fixed in VS Code 1.86.